# Rails - JavaScript view not updating page correctly after Ajax request

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Questions`, which can be voted on. When I list each question on the question's index, I put the "yes" vote and "no" vote buttons alongside each one. I am trying to use Ajax to create votes and render a js view that updates the vote counts.

I'm observing this behavior: 
The votes are successfully created and saved. The first "yes" vote made on each question adjusts the count correctly for that question, but creating any "yes" votes after that will not update the count despite the vote objects being saved. The "no" buttons never update the label correctly. Randomly, clicking on a "No" button will increase that question's no_vote count to 80. If I refresh the page, all the counts update to the correct value as expected.

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :pass_percentage

  has_many :votes
  has_many :yes_votes, class_name: 'Vote', conditions: { is_yes: true }
  has_many :no_votes, class_name: 'Vote', conditions: { is_yes: false }

  ...

end
```

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_yes, :question_id

  belongs_to :question

  validates :is_yes, inclusion: { in: [true, false]}
  validates :question_id, presence: true
end
```

views/questions/index.html.erb

```
...

<%= will_paginate @questions %>
<ul class="questions">
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li>
        <section class="question_<%= question.id %> clearfix">
            <h2><%= link_to question.title, question_path(question) %></h2>
            <p><%= truncate(question.body, length: 70) %></p>
            <div class="vote-buttons">
                <%= render partial: 'shared/yes_vote',
                locals: { question: question } %>
                <%= render partial: 'shared/no_vote', 
                locals: { question: question } %>
            </div>
        </section>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

...
```

_yes_vote.html.erb

```
<div class="vote-btn yes-vote-btn">
<%= form_for question.votes.build(is_yes: true), remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :is_yes %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Yes", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
<span class="yes-votes-count"><%= question.yes_votes.count %></p>
</div>
```

_no_vote.html.erb

```
<div class="vote-btn no-vote-btn">
<%= form_for question.votes.build(is_yes: false), remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :is_yes %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id %>
    <%= f.submit "No", class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
<span class="no-votes-count"><%= question.no_votes.count %></span>
</div>
```

votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @vote = Vote.new
    end

    def create
        @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])
        @question = @vote.question


        respond_to do |format|
            if @vote.save
                format.html { redirect_to :back }
                format.js
            else
                format.html { redirect_to :back, flash: { error: "There was an error" } }
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
end
```

questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @questions = Question.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    ...

end
```

views/vote/create.js.erb

```
$(".question_<%= @question.id %> .yes-votes-count").html("<%= @question.yes_votes.count %>")
$(".question_<%= @question.id %> .no-votes-count").html("<%= @question.no_votes.count %>")
```

Server Log:

```
Started POST "/votes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-17 02:53:38 -0400
Processing by VotesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QD+7gj3G5r68B7cpxxW5ighB5M0Djluxx5XymnG4vog=", "vote"=>{"is_yes"=>"true", "question_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Yes"}
  Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "votes" ("created_at", "is_yes", "question_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 17 May 2013 06:53:38 UTC +00:00], ["is_yes", true], ["question_id", 2], ["updated_at", Fri, 17 May 2013 06:53:38 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."question_id" = 2 AND "votes"."is_yes" = 't'
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."question_id" = 2
  Question Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "questions" WHERE ("questions"."title" = 'Crust or no crust?' AND "questions"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
   (31.9ms)  commit transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."question_id" = 2 AND "votes"."is_yes" = 't'
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."question_id" = 2 AND "votes"."is_yes" = 'f'
  Rendered votes/create.js.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 2.3ms | ActiveRecord: 32.6ms)
```

Sorry for the large amount of code. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Why is this not working? Is there a much better way to get write create.js.erb view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out my issue. The problem was in my create.js.erb. I needed to be using the .text() function not .html() to replace the contents of the element.

New code:

```
$(".question_<%= @question.id %> .yes-votes-count").text("<%= @question.yes_votes.count %>")
$(".question_<%= @question.id %> .no-votes-count").text("<%= @question.no_votes.count %>")
```

If anyone sees ways to improve my code in general though, post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote two `@vote.save` condition.Remove the first one and check again.
Must be validation problems as if you are saving same entry two times